# r tiled plot of effect estimates

Tags: r, ggplot2

I like to learn how to reproduce this plot. I dont know what this is called but I am interested to recreate this using this dataset where X is a my predictor variable and M1 is my grouping variable.

So the Fladen = a, Landsort=b, Utlagan=c, etc

TM, RC, S2, S1, MM will be Level = 1, 2,3,4

```
effect_data <- data.frame(
  Level = factor(rep(1:4, each = 12)),
  # Assuming 12 sets of analyses
  EffectEstimate = runif(48, min = -2, max = 2),
  # Replace with your actual effect estimates
  LowerCI = runif(48, min = -3, max = -1),
  # Replace with your actual lower CIs
  UpperCI = runif(48, min = 1, max = 3),
  # Replace with your actual upper CIs
  M1  = factor(rep(letters[1:12], times = 4))
)
```

Expecting a plot like this. Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a so called dot and whisker plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(effect_data, aes(y = Level, x = EffectEstimate)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = LowerCI, xmax = UpperCI), 
                 height = 0,  #removing ticks
                 position = position_dodge(width = 0.3), 
                 color = "gray", alpha = 0.5,
                 size = 3) + 
  geom_point(color = "black", size = 3, position = position_dodge(width = 0.3)) +
  facet_wrap(~ M1, scales = "free_y", ncol = 4) +
  labs(title = "Effect Estimates with 95% CI", y = "Effect Estimate", x = "Level") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    strip.background = element_rect(fill="gray", color="black"), 
    strip.text = element_text(size=14, color="black"),  
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, linewidth = 1.5)
  )
```

[image]